# Is $0$ in the set $K = \{1/n : n\in \Bbb N\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the element $0$ in the set $K = \{1/n : n\in \Bbb N\}$?

And moreover, if $0\in  K$, can we choose it to do operation like `set-minus`, such as resuling in 
$0 \notin(-1,1)-K $?

Comment: No, $0 \not \in K$ because $0 \neq 1/n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Here $0$ is a limit point of $K$.

Comment: Can you write $0 = 1/n$ for some $n$?

Comment: @angryavian maybe possible if I consider $\infty$ not as a state but element..?

Comment: @delinco $\infty$ is not an element of $\mathbb N.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Is there any set which contains $\infty$, such as $A = {\infty}$?

Comment: Well $A=\infty$ does not, generally speaking, contain $\infty.$ But $A=\{\infty \}$ is a set whose only element is $\infty,$ and thus contains $\infty.$ Sure, in any context where $\infty$ is a well-defined mathematical object, there can usually be sets that contain it. For instance the extended reals $[-\infty,\infty]$ often used in calculus have $\infty$ and $-\infty$ as elements. You could even define an ordered set $\mathbb N \cup \{\infty\}$ with an infinite element tacked on as the largest element "at the end" (i.e. after all the naturals). That's not  what $\mathbb N$ is though.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Could you give me formal definition of $\infty$? I defined it by myself like this $\infty = \{x| \exists x_1 s.t. x_1 \neq x \ \forall x\}$

Comment: @delinco: The definition of $\infty$ depends on the context. Yor definition says “$\infty$ is the set of objects that don't exist”, which doesn't look like a sensible definition. I think what you *wanted* to express is that “$\infty$ is an unique additional element that is not an element of the base set”, which *is* a sensible statement, but usually that would not be considered sufficient to consider the extra element to be $\infty$. One possible way to define an infinity for the reals is to declare that $\infty>x$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. This is used e.g. in measure theory.

Comment: @celtschk anyway to generalize the $\infty$ beyond Reals?

Comment: @delinco: Yes and no. The point is, in different contexts, the symbol $\infty$ corresponds to *different* concepts. For example, in topology, it usually refers to the single additional element in the one-point (Alexandrov) compactification of a non-compact space; there's no meaningful separate $-\infty$ going with that. In the surreal numbers, $\infty$ refers to the gap between the finite and the positive infinite numbers. When considering the rank of polynomials, the rank of the zero polynomial is sometimes defined as $-\infty$; however there's no corresponding rank $+\infty$ for polynomials.

Comment: @celtschk any good reference journal article or book that only concentrates on the formal definition of $\infty$ in varying contexts? I would like to read it for fun and for better understanding of some non-countable or non-finite object

Comment: @delinco: I don't know of any, but that of course doesn't necessarily mean that it doesn't exist.

Comment: You can do a proof by contradiction. Suppose $0 \in K \implies 1/n = 0 \implies 1= 0$ This is not true and hence, 0 is not in K

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, no, $0 \not \in K$. Were $0 \in K$, then there would exist some $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $1/n = 0$. But multiplying by $n$, a nonzero quantity, on both sides would imply $0=1$, a contradiction. Sure, it is true that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1 n = 0$$

but this is only a "limiting behavior," i.e. it is what the function approaches as $n$ grows larger and larger, and makes no statement as to whether some such element satisfies $1/n = 0$. (Nor does it suggest $\infty \in \Bbb N$. Infinity is an entity entirely separate from the natural numbers.)

---

*...granted, this question is quite old, so I imagine you don't need help now. But hopefully this helps someone in the future, and, if nothing else, gets this question out of the unanswered queue.*